# Load javascript resources using AJAX in Webworker

Tags: javascript, ajax, resources, load, web-worker

I am creating a Single Page Application, a little framework for myself.
I am using native Javascript, no external dependencies, no jQuery, nothing.

Here's what I'd like to do:

After first visiting the page, my framework synchronously loads only resources needed to render the current page. Afterwards, when everything's loaded for the current page, I create new Webworker. I want him to load other .js files, representing other pages on the site. Each of those files conatin exactly one object, which represents the page - I want this object to be globally available in the main thread. In my head, webworker should start loading dependencies one-by-one via ajax calls, and everytime he loads something, he should inform main thread via postmessage, and send the file to main thread (not sure wheter send whole ajax responseText back to the main thread, or write it to sessionStorage - I would appretiate recommendations even on this topic).

BUT. Here's a problem.
I need to EXECUTE this file - I want my objects to be globally availabe to my main-thread. I know I can't do something like this:

```
function loadScript(url, callback)
{
    // Adding the script tag
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;

    // Then bind the event to the callback function.
    // There are several events for cross browser compatibility.
    script.onreadystatechange = callback;
    script.onload = callback;

    // Fire the loading
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Because I can't access the DOM from the webworker thread.

So the question is.
Is there a better solution then send responseText string back to the main thread, and then call eval() on it? I heard that eval is evil, slow and buggy.
But do I have other choice?

Every recommendation, even the ones that would tear my framework concept apart is much appretiated.

Here's my github profile, but dont inspect it too much, it's nowhere near finished, and there might be a pretty stupid mistakes, and documentation is written in my native languague.
https://github.com/congrady/Bakalarka

Comment: Hi. I don't think what you want to do is useful at all. You should load all dependencies *asynchronously* in the main thread. When the file is being downloaded the UI thread is not blocked - only when it's executed. And since you want to execute them anyway, using web worker will not make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea seems perfectly feasible -- you can return any (well, almost any) data you want from the worker to the main thread, so I would avoid just returning the string and `eval`-ing things.  When receiving the data from the worker, the main thread could make it accessible however it wants (including adding stuff to the `window` object to make it globally available).

There are some advantages to making Ajax calls in a web worker.  For instance, if you expect a large response (i.e. multiple MBs of JSON or binary image data) to be returned, the main thread may hang while interpreting and parsing the response.  A web worker can handle this asynchronously... I've done similar things for [a BackboneJS plugin I developed](https://github.com/pwagener/backbone.conduit) for managing large-scale data sets in the browser.

Within the web worker, I suggest finding a small Ajax library to simplify the management of the Ajax requests.  I ended up using [Nanoajax](https://github.com/yanatan16/nanoajax), and have been very happy with it.

Note if the data returned from your server is going to include functions along with the data, you'll either need to go with the eval'ed String approach or something similar.